# Jquery behaves differently

Tags: jquery, click, jsfiddle

I am trying to develop a date picker. I am preparing an entire calendar in a JavaScript string and appending it to a `div` element.  The problem is that the jQuery click event behaves differently. If I write the entire code in a .js file on `$(document).ready()` event and add that script file at top of the HTML file, the click events are not working properly (Meaning, if I'm in the month of March, if I click next, the calendar is navigating to the next month April, but then afterward, whenever I click it, I'm always getting the old month).

If I write the entire script at the bottom of the html file (after the body tag), it works fine.

When I put that code in jsFiddle. It works there too. I think they append script code at bottom of the page.

What could be wrong if the code is in a `$(document).ready()` event handler?  Here is [the jsFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/ramstheroyal/hvbEs/2/).

Comment: Do you get any JavaScript errors when running with the JS at the top of your HTML?

Comment: No.It is not giving any errors..It works fine upto first click..Then onwards its not working properly..

Answer (score 0):

I assume this is happening for you in IE.  I was able to reproduce it.  The browser was shown to be running in "quirks mode."  When it's in this mode, the `indexOf` function for `Array` is undefined.  This JavaScript error prevents the proper functioning of the calendar picker.  Switching away from quirks mode fixed the issue.

To fix, you can ensure that you have a proper `DOCTYPE` defined for the page or have a meta tag like `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />` that avoids quirks mode.

I'm not sure yet why moving the script triggers different modes.  Perhaps someone else on SO knows the answer to that.

Comment: I run it in IE 9..It gives me right index.The problem is that,when ever click next,I get the month name of tag whose id is DP_MONTH, find the index of the month from monthArray, and then increment it.$('#DP_MONTH').text() comes right way in first click.But on next click on wards,It always gives March though the tag has another month name, ,So that It shows April month only on every next click.I hope u got my point.....

Comment: I cannot reproduce that happening.  Could you post your HTML so we can see how exactly you are including your script when this problem starts happening?